# Максимальное кол-во айдишников в WHERE IN(...)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть запрос, и в нем использую порядка 500 айдишников, перечисленных в IN

```
UPDATE `table` SET `age` = '0-18' WHERE IN(1,2,3,4,5.....500);
```

Запрос обрабатывает быстро, но возник вопрос, а есть ли ограничение на кол-во перечисляемых айдишников в IN?

Comment: _Я .csv файлы парсить начал, а там по 100к строк..._ Если всё это выполняется в рамках одного хоста, подумайте о создании временной таблицы (`ENGINE=Memory`), импорте файла (через `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`) и использовании её в запросе на обновление. Возможно, даже с созданием нужного для запроса индекса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Будет работать, пока не будет превышен max_allowed_packet

Answer (score 1):

500 штук явно не с воздуха ж берутся, скорее всего их можно как-то получить по условиям, тогда запрос приобретает естественную локаничность и крысату:

```
update tabl SET age = '0-18' WHERE id = (SELECT id from ... WHERE ...)
```

но если уж вот так руками надо указать (ну бывает - асенила) тогда создать временную табличку ttbl с одним полем id (для крысаты сделать его PK), вписать или загрузить туда ихъ, и тоже

```
update tabl SET age = '0-18' WHERE id = (SELECT id from ttbl)
```

или так

```
update tabl SET age = '0-18' WHERE id IN (SELECT id from ttbl)
```

Comment: 500 не предел, я для примера указал 500, а так в среднем значение варьируется от 900 до 1.500. Я .csv файлы парсить начал, а там по 100к строк...

Comment: ну если это для программы парсинга запрос - тогда нужно пачками по несколько сотен отправлять запросы:  накопилось скажем 200 - отправили запрос. так и серверу проще и вам спокойнее